# Where are my volumes mounted when using Docker Desktop and WSL2?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volume, wsl-2, persistent-volumes

I am using Docker Desktop and Docker Kubernetes with WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). I have a yaml file for a persistent volume that mounts the volume in /mnt/data. Where is this located since there is nothing when I do "ls /mnt/data" in WSL even as sudo?

```
hostPath:
  path: "/mnt/data"
```

ls /mnt/data

ls: cannot access '/mnt/data': No such file or directory

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the disk you're trying to access in the path. For example, if you're trying to access disk C:

path: "/mnt/c/data"

You can double check by going into your /mnt path and executing an `ls` so that you see all the directories.

Comment: Hi Alvaro. The storage has been provisioned and used for a database, this persists between deployments/containers but I have no idea where it's being stored. If I change the path to /mnt/c/data then it'll just be stored again in this hidden location rather than /mnt/c/data and visible in WSL.


Within "/mnt/" are just C: and WSL share so it doesn't look to be hiding within mnt.

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding your question correctly, but your data is stored inside the docker container you created, not your wsl. In your case, if u access your container as i mentioned before, you should be able to do (cd /mnt/data) and there should be all the data

Answer (score 0):

The data isn't stored on your local machine but on the worker node running your cluster, e.g. the minikube vm. You need to connect to that machine to find the data.

E.g. for minikube:

```sh
minikube ssh
ls /mnt/data
```

Comment: He does not write that he is using minikube, right?

Comment: Last time I checked Docker Desktop referred to minikube for running Kubernetes on Windows, but that has been a while. Fact is that the data will be stored on the "vm" that is the worker node. Updated my answer.